# Hiding the focus box on Swing components

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, focus, jslider

In Java, is it possible to hide the dotted-line box that appears when you give Swing components GUI focus? This isn't usually a problem for me but it just looks messy on my JSlider.

Comment: could you provide an example and/or image?

Comment: I think that [TrashGod's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20288489/522444) is what you want. If it helps you, then please up-vote it.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels, thank you, I thought I'd searched thoroughly enough, didn't think to try the word 'border' instead of box. I can't 'up' it until I have 15 reps.